# Problems with types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, casting

I have some problems with the different types in Haskell, how can I solve this?

Couldn't match expected type `Integer` with actual type `Int -> t0 -> t0`

Thanks

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime number
    | (number == 1) || (number == 2) = True
    | even number = False
    | otherwise = checkDiv number (fromInteger (`sqrt` number))

checkDiv :: Int -> Int -> Bool
checkDiv number divisor 
    | number == 2 = True
    | (floor number `mod` divisor) == 0 = False
    | otherwise = checkDiv number $ divisor - 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve with this problem?

Comment: Why did you put `sqrt` in backticks?  Just use `(sqrt number)`.

Comment: isPrime number should be true if number is a prime number, and false if not, but I want to use this algorithm

Comment: you can't take `sqrt` of `number` because it is an `Int` not a `Floating`.  And `fromInteger` is for `Integer`.  `fromIntegral` is for any `Integral` type.

Comment: Note that 1 isn't prime.

Answer (score 7):

I've figured out the modifications to get the code to compile, but it does not actually find primes.  I had to change

```
fromInteger (`sqrt` number)
```

to

```
floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral number
```

The backtick notation around a function name is to turn it in to an infix "operator" of sorts, so you could do

```
mod x y
```

or

```
x `mod` y
```

but not

```
`mod` x y
```

Next, you were using `fromInteger` instead of `fromIntegral`, which is the one that works on `Int`s (`Int` and `Integer` are different types).  Finally, I removed the `floor` from `number` in the second guard of `checkDiv`, since `number` is already an `Int`.

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime number
    | (number == 1) || (number == 2) = True
    | even number = False
    | otherwise = checkDiv number (floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral number)

checkDiv :: Int -> Int -> Bool
checkDiv number divisor
    | number == 2 = True
    | (number `mod` divisor) == 0 = False
    | otherwise = checkDiv number $ divisor - 1
```

So let's work through your code so that you can see what's going on.  If I were to compute `checkDiv 17 4` (`4` is `floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral 17`), it would perform

```
checkDiv 17 4
    | 17 == 2            No
    | 17 `mod` 4 == 0    No
    | otherwise = checkDiv 17 (4 - 1) = checkDiv 17 3

checkDiv 17 3
    | 17 == 2            No
    | 17 `mod` 3 == 0    No
    | otherwise = checkDiv 17 (3 - 1) = checkDiv 17 2

checkDiv 17 2
    | 17 == 2            No
    | 17 `mod` 2 == 0    No
    | otherwise = checkDiv 17 (2 - 1) = checkDiv 17 1

checkDiv 17 1
    | 17 == 2            No
    | 17 `mod` 1 == 0    Yes    = False
```

But `17` is prime!  Do you see where your algorithm is doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should be divisor instead of number == 2.

Comment: Correct, that makes the algorithm complete (other than considering 1 a prime, but not a big deal).  My next question to you is how can you make this run faster?  You're checking ever single number between 2 and `sqrt number` to see if it's a factor, but you already filter out all even numbers.  Is there a simple way you could modify your program to only check odd divisors?